# scala multi sbt project: object is not a member of package, not found type

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I import class `abc` from project `main` to be used by another class in project `web` in a `multi-project sbt` configuration?

Upon `sbt compile` I get:
`object abc is not a member of package com`
`not found: type abc`

While compilation from within IntelliJ is successful.

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val main = project.in(file("main"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val web = project.in(file("web"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(main)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(web, main)
  .aggregate(web, main)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)


mainClass in root in Compile := (mainClass in web in Compile).value

fullClasspath in web in Runtime ++= (fullClasspath in main in Runtime).value

fullClasspath in root in Runtime ++= (fullClasspath in web in Runtime).value
```

Inside **web project**:

```
package com.company.web.controllers
import _root_.com.company.main.abc // also tried without root. 
// Intellij recognizes the import successuflly

class Posts @Inject() (repo : abc) extends Controller { ..
```

Inside **main project**:

```
package com.company.main
class abc @Inject() (){
```

What could be wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full error message. I suspect you shadow something. Your code above looks correct. You don't need `fullClasspath ... ++=`, if you have `dependsOn` it implies the classes are on the path. Could it be that `@Inject` fiddles around with the byte-code? If it's shadowing, you might rename the import for test purposes, such as `import main.{abc => ABC}`

Comment: Thanks for `fullClasspath` tip. Removed it and `@Inject` but result was the same

Comment: "While compilation from within IntelliJ is successful" - IntelliJ uses sbt for compilation, so either you mean the presentation compiler doesn't indicate an error, or you are really building the project? If that is the case, you must have a confusion with running sbt from the terminal, perhaps wrong directory (picks up a different build / project)?

Comment: I really build the project and it runs, and after successful compilation from intelij, running `sbt compile` also succeeds, but `sbt clean compile` fails. 

Turns out, that `sbt "project main" "compile"` doesnt build anything at all. `target` remains empty. Probably `intelij` compiles those files because they are marked as `source directory` within intelij, while `sbt` misses them because of invalid directory structure..

Answer (score 4):

Turned out the directory structure of project `main` wasn't according to `maven` directory structure, as [described here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Directories.html)

```
src/
  main/
    scala/
       com/bla/bla
  test/
    scala/
       <test Scala sources
```

Intellij was successfully compiling the project because whatever old directory structure was in place, it was marked as `source directory` under `File -> project structure -> modules -> sources`

Answer (score 0):

had the same error, for a similar reason

i had

```scala
lazy val Project_1 =
  Project(
    id = "project-1",
    base = file("./project-1/"),
  )
  .settings(
    sourceDirectory := file("./src/main/scala/"),
  )
```

but correct is

```scala
  .settings(
    sourceDirectory := file("./src/"),
  )
```

`./src/main/scala/` looks like

```
$ tree src/main/scala/
src/main/scala/
└── org.myorganization.myname
    └── myproject
        ├── MySource1.scala
        └── MySource1.scala
```